Move QgsMapCanvasItem on canvas with PyQGIS
Which is best option to move custom QgsMapCanvasItem on map canvas by mose move?
First of all i have MapTool connected to on_move method, and class with map canvas item.
class testCanvasItem(QgsMapCanvasItem):
def __init__(self, canvas):
    super().__init__(canvas)
    self.point = QgsPointXY(10, 10)
    self.screen_point = self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.point)

def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option=None, widget=None):
    painter.drawText(QPoint(0, 0), "test")

def repaint(self, point):
    self.point = point
    self.screen_point = self.toCanvasCoordinates(self.point)

def boundingRect(self):
    return QRectF(-20, -20, 20, 20)

I found 2 ways to do what I want:

Use draw_item.update():
 def on_move(self, point):
     self.draw_item.repaint(point)
     self.draw_item.setPos(self.draw_item.screen_point)
     self.draw_item.update(self.draw_item.boundingRect())



Which isn't good because item have trail, like old Windows windows

Use canvas.refresh():
 def on_move(self, point):
 self.draw_item.repaint(point)
 self.draw_item.setPos(self.draw_item.screen_point)
 self.canvas.refresh()



But my project is heavy and this way works slowly (and also have a trail sometimes)
I also tried using painter.drawText(self.screen_point, "test") insted of setPos(), but it have same result. I saw some questions here about same issue, but answers didn't work for me.
Guess i'm missing somethin important
